# How can I add new attributes in a Class when my addon is active?

Tags: hooks

I already have a class object named `People` in my plugin.

*PHP People Class*

```
namespace MyPlugin\Common;

class People{

    public $people_id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public function __construct( $data ){
        $this->people_id = $data["people_id"];
        $this->first_name = $data["first_name"];
        $this->last_name = $data["last_name"];
    }

    public function save(){

         global $wpdb;

         $data = array(
             "first_name" => $this->first_name,
             "last_name" => $this->last_name
          );

          $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . PLUGIN_PREFIX . 'people', $data );

          return $wpdb->insert_id;

   }

}
```

I would like when I active an addon, `People` is improved with an attribute as array to get/set more informations like this following result :

*PHP People Class with addon activation*

```
namespace MyPlugin\Common;

class People{

    public $people_id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public $options = array(); //<-- add an array

    public function __construct( $data ){
        $this->people_id = $data["people_id"];
        $this->first_name = $data["first_name"];
        $this->last_name = $data["last_name"];

        $this->options = $data['options']; //<-- set more information
    }

    //Override the save function to save $this->options

    /*  magic method set */
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    /*  magic method get */
    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) return $this->data[$name];
        else return false;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to do this with a hook function or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a location for this data in your class, like an array beforehand and then use it like below:

```
class test {
  private $first_name;
  private $data = array();

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->data[$name] = $value;
  }

  public function __get($name) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data))
        return $this->data[$name];
    else
        return 'not found';
  }
}

$try = new test();
$try->last_name = 'jhon';

echo $try->last_name;
```

Then look at the [register_activation_hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) from Wordpress.

You can also read more about Magic Methods on the PHP website: http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: Test class is in your addon ?

Comment: This is just an example, not sure what you mean. The idea is that if you access a property that doesn't exist, the __get() magic method will be called and return accordingly. Same thing when you try to assign a value to a non-existent property by using __set().

Comment: Yes I know that, I get this information thanks this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320723/how-can-i-add-dynamicaly-new-attribute-for-a-class-in-php-thanks-new-db-column-n). It's already written in my code. I would like to know more about how to override my main plugin class  inside an addon.